# how to load external div into a master.html div from a number of submenu items

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, submenu

I am using a submenu to display a div from an external html file in a div in the master.html file.

I have looked through at least 20 examples of similar related things but cannot for the life of me get my code to work and unfortunately while I know why I don't know how to solve the problem.

So I have a sub menu defined in css:

```
#subnav ul li#subone a:hover{color:#ffffff; background-color: #1e3435;}
```

I Have master.html with the html for the submenu

```
<div id="subnav" >
    <ul>
        <li id="subone"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li id="subtwo"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>

</div>
```

And I am using this javascript code with the jquery.js included in the header:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".subnav ul li a") .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#content2').load( 'abc.html' );
    });
});
</script>
```

I know something is wrong here but can't quite figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your title should be a question, not a collection of tags.

Comment: so sorry it is literally the first time i have ever posted here and will make sure that is the case in future .apologies

Comment: No worries, when you have a few minutes take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance:

```
$(".subnav ul li a").click(...)
```

Should be

```
$("#subnav ul li a").click(...)
```

Because you have used `<div id="subnav" >`. Use `#` for `id` and `.` for class.

**Update:** To load content from a particular element you may use this:

```
$("#content2").load("abc.html  #container");
```

Here, `#container` is the `id` of the element and only this element's html will be loaded into target `div`, so make sure you use the right `identifier`. Read more on [jQuery website](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

**Update:** You may use one function/handler for all of your menu items:

```
$(function(){
    $(".subnav ul li a") .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#content2').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content');
    });
});
```

Make sure your all `pages/html` file contains same `#content` so every time you click on any menu item, the appropriate `html` file would be loaded into `$('#content2')` div bt only `#content` part of the page and also provide proper link (`href='filename.html'`) for all menu items.

If your all pages don't have the same `id` as `#content` then add a `data-target='identifier'` in each `a` tag, like this:

```
<div id="subnav" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href='abc.html' data-target='content'>Abc</a></li>
        <li><a href='def.html' data-target='someid'>Edf</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So in this case, you may use something like this:

```
$('#content2').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target'));
```

Comment: fair point ... i just copied and pasted my original #nav in the css and added #subnav to it .... maybe i should of made it a class but perhaps that is another matter , thanks for pointing out the first glance

Comment: at the moment the div tags ARE actually being pulled into the master.html but it seems that it isn't distringuishing between the divs and just plonking the whole div in the master.html div area.  this is the abc.html body ....                                                                                        <body>
<div id="content2"><p>this is a test to see what will happen if i pull in the html </p></div>
  <div id="content3"><p>Here comes some content  </p></div>
</body>

Comment: ----- this is the web console ----                                           TypeError: $(...).nivoSlider is not a function index.html:41
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: ah ok so i am confused between the entire content of abc.html ( which is absolutely happening ) and that I only want a particular div from the abc.html which would be great .... alternatively I guess I will have to do the function 9 times for each menu item perhaps

Comment: i am ignoring the nivo slider issue as I changed the name of the header ref from jquery1.7.1-min.js to -- jquery.js .... figured it would elimitate the specific variables concerned with this specific issue... once i fix this I will change the names back :p

Comment: I THINK IVE DONE IT WITH THE HELP SO FAR ! so just need to do nine of the scripts below for each menu item ... maybe i will just use seperate pages
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#subone") .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#content2').load( 'abc.html' );
    });
});
</script>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#subtwo") .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#content2').load( 'abc2.html' );
    });
});
</script>

Comment: all i need to do now is hope that cross platform will support ajax/jquery and hope that the html being pulled into the master will conform to the css of the div containers in the master, (which it doesn't seem to be doing but hey at least it works.... kinda

Comment: Hey Wolf thanks muchly for the update... couple of things .... firstly is it not #submenu and not .submenu based on your earlier comment and also .... how do i assign this function to each menu item without applying it to the li tags ?  hope you got some rest buddy !

Comment: by the way I am guessing its the ul li a bit in the function that somehow will automatically assign stuff for each submenu item but not sure .... gonna try it out anyways

Comment: Hi there, bit of a strange one have put the code together but on clicking the menu item it does nothing... if i right click and open in a new tab of course it just opens the whole web page in a new tab... not sure what is going on ... Any ideas ?

Comment: jquery is loaded and am getting this error   --------------------------SyntaxError: missing ; before statement and the line in question is ----------------------------------------------- $('#whatismt_content').load('abc.html')+ '#' + $(this).attr('data-target'));  ---------------------------------------------------------where the code ive got for the whole thing is I am posting it on the next comment

Comment: <div id="submenu">
 <div id="subnav" >
   <ul>
    <li id="subone"><a href="#" data-target='content2'>Definitions</a></li>
    <li id="subtwo"><a href="#" data-target='content3'>History</a></li>
   
                 
   </ul>
 </div>

</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#subnav ul li a") .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
      $('#whatismt_content').load('abc.html')+ '#' + $(this).attr('data-target')); 

    });
});
</script>

<div id="#whatismt_content">
</div>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949548/load-external-html-div-into-master-html-div-using-multiple-menu-items-and-one-js

Comment: the new question is now causing problems with admin i think -- i may be going crazy here