# load external html div into master.html div using multiple menu items and one JS statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the current state of the code to load a div from abc.html into master.html div called whatis_content . I want to do this for all menu items

```
<div id="submenu">
<div id="subnav" >
        <ul>




    <li id="subone"><a href="abc.html" data-target='content2'>Definitions</a> </li>



    <li id="subtwo"><a href="abc.html" data-target='content3'>History</a></li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

```
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
     $("#subnav ul li a").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault()
         $('#whatismt_content')
         .load($(this).attr('abc.html') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target'));
      });
  });
  </script>
```

THIS IS THE EXTERNAL HTML FILE FOR ABC.HTML

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="whatis.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="content2"><p>BAH BLAHA BH;AHABHBAKBAHBAhtml </p></div>
```

Here comes some content comes some

```
<div id="#whatismt_content">

</div>
```

Comment: Edit your old question, and don't accept answers unless it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't code properly, just try this changes:

```
$(function(){
    $("#subnav ul li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
        $('#whatismt_content').load(url);
    });
});
```

Don't change `' #'` to `'#'`, copy and paste exact code.

Comment: no still not doing anything very strange ????

Comment: this is really perplexing

Comment: still no change very odd

Comment: maybe I am just gonna have to do individual statements for every menu item ?

Comment: AH , apologies for that I thought I was meant to put the html file name in there.... I changed it back but still no change ... I have posted the abc.html file above . it really is basic so not sure if it would cause a problem

Comment: yes they are all in the same dirctory

Comment: Remove the `#` from `<div id="#whatismt_content">` this is the problem.

Comment: I am so sorry for wasting your time with my careless mistake ! --- thanks so much for your help !

Comment: sorry i will accept that one as well if that helps you ,.... RUJordan told me about the last one and said i would change it